# Where to set code to limit a users access without using web.config

Tags: vb.net, authentication, redirect

I have a website that I want to be able to restrict which pages the admin user can access.  I know I could probably do something in the web.config, but this is a web site that will be given to someone else to host and I don't want anyone else to be able to set the pages that can be seen by the admin.

So when the admin user tries to go to a page I don't want him to see, which event would be best place to add my re-direct code that will take them to the default page I do want them to see, eg.

```
Application_EndRequest()
Application_AuthenticateRequest()
Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute()
```

My project is vb.net.

Hope someone can give me some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I needed to secure a client application/website based on acccess level, ie; sysadmin, admin, user, etc.  Using the web.config was once solution, but like you I needed to grant/deny access without giving it up in web.config.  I ended up using a public constant on each page which described the minimum access level for that page, yes it was a bit tedious, but it did exactly what I needed.  Code:

```
Public Const accesslevel As integer = 999 ' System Admin level, you always want to leave room between levels so if you need to add levels later it's easier to do so.
' In the page load event
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' I have a user class where I store all the user information.  I store in in the session.
    If not MyUser.AccessLevel >= accesslevel Then
        Response.Redirect(Session(camefrom)) '"camefrom" is a Session variable and is set to the page the user came from
    End If
End Sub
```

Yes I realize that this is a bit tedious and there are probably a gazillion different ways to address this issue, but this is what I used then and continue to use today.  NOTE:  There are some pages where I test the access level BEFORE I go to the page, necessary because of session state.  This method gives me control over each page and prevents the access levels from being circumvented.

Comment: Thanks Prescott.  I have a mixture of asp pages and a RESTful Service running together, so the approach would only help in the asp pages, I would still need to stop access on the REST side of things.

Comment: With my web services I require a username and password with each method.  I enforce level access on the data basically using the same method and it protects the data from unauthorized access.